# I'm trying to send/share mp3 raw file via whatsapp or any other messenger app.

Tags: java, android

```
public void share(String song){

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.dsbsoft.myApp/raw/"+song+".mp3");

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Send song"));
}
```

all works perfectly but at the time to send the file, i think, it's not exists...
In the void comes String variable song, that contains the name of file.
For example:
the call was: share("abc"); i want to send the mp3 file(it is in raw folder) abc.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we can't send directly resourse files.
Thats why i do the following.
To send mp3 file, i burn it on a folder in the storage and share this new file.

the code:

```
public void makeOutSide(String song, InputStream ins){
    // Create the directory
    File dir = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.CSOUNDS/");
    // If it does not exists, make it.
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir(); // Generating the directory
    }
    try {
        // Open the resource
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
        ins.read(buffer);
        ins.close();
        // Burn
        String filename = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/.CSOUNDS/"+song+".mp3";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {  }
}

public void share(String song, InputStream ins){
    makeOutSide(song,ins);
    String rout = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/.CSOUNDS/"+song+".mp3";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(rout);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share song"));
}
```

in the call of the share method comes an `InputStream ins` at this way:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.abc);
share("abc",ins);
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. In the future do not answer your own questions, rather edit your question stating what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void share(String song){ 


    File audio = new File("android.resource://com.dsbsoft.myApp/raw/+song+ ".mp3");

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("audio/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(audio));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share song"));

}
```

Comment: not working. the same error when push ok to send via whatsapp.

Comment: Check out your typos. This `new File("android.resource://com.dsbsoft.myApp/raw/+song+ ".mp3")` won't work.

Comment: are you talking about the sintax? 
new File("android.resource://com.dsbsoft.myApp/raw/" + song + ".mp3");
that is the correct line, but it isn't work

Comment: Please post your logcat. If you have the name of the file in your `raw` folder, so then you can just do `File audio = new File("android.resource://com.dsbsoft.myApp/raw/abc.mp3);`

Comment: i can't run emulators, i test it on my phone.

Comment: I did not say anything about emulators? Can you please post your log?

Comment: public void Acción (Cadena Canción) {Uri uri = Uri.parse ( "android.resource: //" + getPackageName () + "/ prima /" + Canción); Intención cuota = new Intención (Intent.ACTION_SEND); share.setType ( "audio / *"); share.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); share.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); startActivity (Intent.createChooser (Acción, "canción Compartir")); } Funciona Perfectamente TODO CUANDO Envío por Correo, La Unidad, Pero No CUANDO Intento un Través de WhatsApp y Facebook Messenger, Porque se ha Eliminado La extensión del archivo